# WebStorm - Adding a breakpoint to every line in a method

Tags: ide, webstorm

I'm new to WebStorm and was wondering: is there a way to add a breakpoint to every line of a selected method?

I have a few methods that are around 60 lines and adding a breakpoint and removing them, line by line, is a little annoying.

Comment: Why do you need breakpoint on every line of the single method? What's wrong with usual "Step Over" (execute current line/statement and move to the next one)?

Comment: That works. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this link -- you may find it useful (you seems to be new to debugging with IDE): 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/debugging.html?search=debug ; 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/stepping-through-the-program.html?search=debug